# How can time.Duration use operators in Go?

Tags: go, operator-overloading, operators

from my understanding operators are only defined for builtin types and can't be defined for user types so:

```
a := 1
b := 2
c := a + b // possible
```

but as soon as you define your own types you need to do:

```
a := NewType(1)
b := NewType(2)
c := a + b // is not possible
c := a.Plus(b) // is possible
```

but when using time.Duration I'm able to do:

```
a := time.Duration(1)
b := time.Duration(2)
c := a + b // is possible
```

So I probably miss something.

Comment: look at the type declaration, [`time.Duration`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-types) is an `int64`

Comment: There is no concept of Operator overloading in Go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arithmetic operators are defined for numeric types, and some of them are defined for string types. If the underlying type of a derived type supports a set of operators, those operators are also supported for the derived type.

In your example, `Duration` is a int64, so all operators defined for int64 works for `Duration`.